# Sort list of strings considering two different criteria

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
l = ['hey (0)', 'hey (1)', 'bye (3)', 'bye (1)']
```

And I want to sort it firstly by the numerical character and then alphabeticly

The output should be:

```
l = ['hey (0)','bye (1)', 'hey (1)', 'bye (3)']
```

tried:

```
l.sort(key = lambda x: (x[-2], x[1]))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is nearly correct. One mistake is that `x[1]` sorts elements with the same numeric value by the second letter, not the first.

Your solution also does generalize well to other inputs. For example, it might place `"produce (5)"` after `"product (5)"` because you are not looking at all of the letters in the word.

You should use the entire beginning of the string (`x[:-4]` will cut off the number, parentheses, and space), and optionally convert the numbers to integers:

```py
>>> l = ['hey (0)', 'hey (1)', 'bye (3)', 'bye (1)']
>>> l.sort(key=lambda x: (int(x[-2]), x[:-4]))
>>> l
['hey (0)', 'bye (1)', 'hey (1)', 'bye (3)']
```

This is still not fully general - for instance, it only works if the numbers are guaranteed to be integers between 0 and 9, otherwise `"foo (11)"` may appear smaller than `"foo (9)"`. In that case, you may want to use something more like azro's solution.

Comment: good answer, could even be simpler: `lambda x: (x[-2],x)`

Comment: Does it work for:
l = ['hejdjdjsadksjady (0)', 'hey (1)', 'bfsdfsdfsye (3)', 'byedfs (1)'] ?

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @holapapimunhanho Not sure what you did, but yes, it should work. I get
`['hejdjdjsadksjady (0)', 'byedfs (1)', 'hey (1)', 'bfsdfsdfsye (3)']`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to more precise `x[-2]` takes the digit (but as a string) but `x[1]` takes the 2nd char, you need the whole word, a regex could do it nicely

```
import re
pattern = re.compile("(\w+) \((\d+)\)")
def sorter(value):
    text, nb = pattern.findall(value)[0]
    return int(nb), text

l = ['hey (0)', 'hey (1)', 'bye (3)', 'bye (1)']
l.sort(key=sorter)
print(l)  # ['hey (0)', 'bye (1)', 'hey (1)', 'bye (3)']
```

Or without regex

```
def sorter(value):
    text, nb = value.split(" ")
    return int(nb.strip("()")), text

l = ['hey (0)', 'hey (1)', 'bye (3)', 'bye (1)']
l.sort(key=sorter)
print(l)  # ['hey (0)', 'bye (1)', 'hey (1)', 'bye (3)']
```